# boto3: execute_command inside python script

Tags: python, aws-sdk

I am trying to run a command to an ecs container managed by fargate. I can establish connection as well as execute successfully but I cannot get the response from said command inside my python script.

```
import boto3
import pprint as pp

client = boto3.client("ecs")
cluster = "my-mundane-cluster-name"


def main():
    task_arns = client.list_tasks(cluster=cluster, launchType="FARGATE")
    for task_arn in task_arns.get("taskArns", []):
        cmd_out = client.execute_command(
            cluster=cluster,
            command="ls",
            interactive=True,
            task=task_arn,
        )
        pp.pprint(f"{cmd_out}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I replaced the command with `ls` but for all intents and purposes, the flow is the same. Here is what I get as a reposnse

```
{
    'clusterArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:■■■■■■■■■■■■:■■■■■■:cluster/■■■■■■',
    'containerArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:■■■■■■■■■■■■:■■■■■■:container/■■■■■■/■■■■■■/■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■',
    'containerName': '■■■■■■',
    'interactive': True,
    'session': {
        'sessionId': 'ecs-execute-command-■■■■■■■■■',
        'streamUrl': '■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■',
        'tokenValue': '■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■'
    },
    'taskArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:■■■■■■■■■■■■:■■■■■■■■■:task/■■■■■■■■■/■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': '■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'x-amzn-requestid': '■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■',
            'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
            'content-length': '■■■',
            'date': 'Thu, 29 Jul 2021 02:39:24 GMT'
        },
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}
```

I've tried running the command as non-interactive to see if it returns a response but the sdk says `Interactive is the only mode supported currently`. I've also tried searching online for clues as to how to do this but no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the error message which you got when you tried to run in non-interactive mode, it's because "Amazon ECS only supports initiating interactive sessions" ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the command output is located within the document stream located at `streamId`. You must initialize a new session and pass it the sessionID to retrieve it's contents.

crude example:

```py
import boto3
import pprint as pp

client = boto3.client("ecs")
ssm_client = boto3.client("ssm")
cluster = "my-mundane-cluster-name"


def main():
    task_arns = client.list_tasks(cluster=cluster, launchType="FARGATE")
    for task_arn in task_arns.get("taskArns", []):
        cmd_out = client.execute_command(
            cluster=cluster,
            command="ls",
            interactive=True,
            task=task_arn,
        )
        
        session_response = client.describe_sessions(
            State='Active'|'History',
            MaxResults=123,
            NextToken='string',
            Filters=[
                {
                    'key': 'InvokedAfter'|'InvokedBefore'|'Target'|'Owner'|'Status'|'SessionId',
                    'value': cmd_out["session"]["sessionId"]
                },
            ]
        )

        document_response = client.get_document(
            Name=session_response.sessions[0].document_name,
            DocumentFormat='YAML'|'JSON'|'TEXT'
        )

        pp.pprint(document_response)
```

## References

SSM: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html

SSM #get_document: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_document

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to use `logging` instead of `pprint`:

```
boto3.set_stream_logger('boto3.resources', logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to accomplish a similar task, and it turns out it doesn't work as answered here as far as I can tell. Let me know if that worked for you, and how you implemented it, if so.

For me the solution, was to open a websocket connection given back in the session, and read the output. Like this:

```py
import boto3
import json
import uuid
import construct as c
import websocket

def session_reader(session: dict) -> str:
    AgentMessageHeader = c.Struct(
        "HeaderLength" / c.Int32ub,
        "MessageType" / c.PaddedString(32, "ascii"),
    )

    AgentMessagePayload = c.Struct(
        "PayloadLength" / c.Int32ub,
        "Payload" / c.PaddedString(c.this.PayloadLength, "ascii"),
    )

    connection = websocket.create_connection(session["streamUrl"])
    try:
        init_payload = {
            "MessageSchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "RequestId": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "TokenValue": session["tokenValue"],
        }
        connection.send(json.dumps(init_payload))
        while True:
            resp = connection.recv()
            message = AgentMessageHeader.parse(resp)
            if "channel_closed" in message.MessageType:
                raise Exception("Channel closed before command output was received")
            if "output_stream_data" in message.MessageType:
                break
    finally:
        connection.close()
    payload_message = AgentMessagePayload.parse(resp[message.HeaderLength :])
    return payload_message.Payload


exec_resp = boto3.client("ecs").execute_command(
    cluster=cluster,
    task=task,
    container=container,
    interactive=True,
    command=cmd,
)
print(session_reader(exec_resp["session"]))
```

This is all that to [Andrey's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586300/2081835) on my similar question.

---

For anybody arriving seeking a similar solution, I have created a tool for making this task simple. It is called [interloper](https://github.com/theherk/interloper).