# How can I stop AWS from replacing newlines with carriage returns?

Tags: python, boto3, aws-sdk, tty

If I use the Python boto3 library to run a command on an AWS ECS container using `execute_command` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586300/6423456), and my command is simply `echo -ne '\n'` (a single, explicit newline character), when I read from the websocket stream that has my command's output, the output is `b'\r\n'`.

This isn't a huge deal for commands that produce text output, and can be easily fixed, but if I run a command that produces binary output, this corrupts my data. Although this can be fixed by replacing `\r\n` with `\n` on the client when I read from the websocket stream, another thing that happens is that the bytes `0xfd`, `0xfe`, and `0xff` are not transferred at all. That's a lot harder to fix, since there's no way to know where those bytes were removed from.

The only workaround I have found is to run the command as `bash -c "echo -en '\n' | base64 -w0"`, and decode it back to binary after receiving it. This works, but makes the output ~33% larger, which, for large binary data like what I'm dealing with, increases the download time by minutes.

What is making these changes? Is there a way to disable this? If not, is there a more efficient workaround then base64?

Comment: You're running a command that yields binary output? As a workaround, could you instead persist the binary output to S3 and return the S3 key as text? Also see [What is the most efficient binary to text encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971211/what-is-the-most-efficient-binary-to-text-encoding).